# Cómo llamar diferentes actividades de card view dentro de un recycler view

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Tengo un problema para llamar a una Activity, desde un Button que está dentro de una CardView y ésta está dentro de un RecyclerView, y el RecyclerView está dentro de un tab de un fragmento.

Las activities las inicia desde cualquier button del recycler view, entonces lo que necesito es que cada botón sea "independiente" y lance una actividad diferente.

Mi MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected RecyclerTabLayout mRecyclerTabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Adding Toolbar to Main screen
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Setting ViewPager for each Tabs
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    // Set Tabs inside Toolbar
    mRecyclerTabLayout = (RecyclerTabLayout)
            findViewById(R.id.recycler_tab_layout);
    mRecyclerTabLayout.setUpWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

// Add Fragments to Tabs
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new CardContentFragment(), "tab 1");
    adapter.addFragment(new CardContentFragment(), "tab 2");
    adapter.addFragment(new CardContentFragment(), "tab 3");
    adapter.addFragment(new CardContentFragment(), "tab 4");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Fragmento que se encarga de llenar la Tab con CardView & RecyclerView:

```
public class CardContentFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
    ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return recyclerView;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView picture;
    public TextView name;
    public TextView description;

    public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false));

        picture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);

       //Open Plagas Activity
        Button button = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), PlagasAguacateActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        //Open Enfermedades Activity
        Button button2 = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), EnfermedadesaAguacateActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
/**
 * Adapter to display recycler view.
 */
public class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    // Set numbers of List in RecyclerView.
    private static final int LENGTH = 3;
    private Context context;

    private final String[] mCult;
    private final String[] mCultDesc;
    private final Drawable[] mCultPictures;

    public ContentAdapter(Context context) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        mCult = resources.getStringArray(R.array.places);
        mCultDesc = resources.getStringArray(R.array.place_desc);
        TypedArray a = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.places_picture);
        mCultPictures = new Drawable[a.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < mCultPictures.length; i++) {
            mCultPictures[i] = a.getDrawable(i);
        }
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.picture.setImageDrawable(mCultPictures[position % mCultPictures.length]);
        holder.name.setText(mCult[position % mCult.length]);
        holder.description.setText(mCultDesc[position % mCultDesc.length]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return LENGTH;
    }
}
}
```